# Class Grades probability question

Tags: probability

```
Among 110 students in a probability class, on a three-question exam, 30 get question
1 incorrect, 40 get question 2 incorrect, and 23 get question 3 incorrect. Further, 20
students get both questions 1 and 2 incorrect, 15 get both questions 2 and 3 incorrect,
and 8 get both questions 1 and 3 incorrect, and 7 get all three questions incorrect.

Given that a student gets problem 1 incorrect, what is the probability he gets Problem 2 incorrect?
```

Would this simply be 20/110 because it states `20
    students get both questions 1 and 2 incorrect`?

Or do I need to do something more complicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you have suggested of $\smash{\frac{20}{110}}$ is the probability that a student gets question 2 incorrect **and** he gets problem 1 incorrect.  However, this is not what was asked: the question wants the probability that a student gets question 2 incorrect **given** that he gets question 1 incorrect.

This means, consider **only** the students who got question 1 incorrect and ignore all the other students.  Out of these students, what is the probability that a student got question 2 incorrect?

Therefore we are considering $30$ students (first piece of information in the problem).  We want to know how many of these students (who got question 1 incorrect) **also** got question 2 incorrect, that is, how many got both question 1 and 2 incorrect: the answer is $20$ (fourth piece of information in the problem).  So the answer is $\smash{\frac{20}{30}}$.

**Comment**.  Note that most of the information specified in the problem is irrelevant!  In my view this is an excellent problem for finding out whether students actually understand the topic.